# Error migración tablas a bbdd con laravel

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin

estoy empezando con el laravel y me está dando guerra la migración de tablas a base de datos desde consola de comandos.

Laravel lo uso desde maquina virtual y uso vagrant y git para ejecurtarlo, al igual que el phpmyadmin tambien está en la maquina. Por otro lado, tengo los archivos de creación de tablas y cuando ejecuto el comando `php artisan migrate` me marca un mensaje de error. He probado varias soluciones y no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

Este es el mensaje que aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito:
Añado el código de la migración:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateArticulosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Nombre_articulo');
            $table->int('Precio');
            $table->string('Pais_origen');
            $table->text('Observaciones');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articulos');
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega la migración que falla

Comment: Tienes un typo, el tipo de dato se declara como `integer`: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#columns

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

Gracias al comentario de BetaM. Me fallaba el tipo de dato, lo he cambiado a integer y se ha creado sin problema alguno.

¡Muchas gracias!